# wheel event brokes mousewheel javascript

Tags: javascript

In latest Chrome there are two wheel events: `wheel` and `mousewheel`.

So this code works good:

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function () {
   console.log('mousewheel fires');
}, false);
```

But in this case:

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function () {
   console.log('mousewheel never fires');
}, false);
document.addEventListener('wheel', function () {
   console.log('wheel fires');
}, false);
```

`mousewheel` doesn't work.

So if I write some third-party script (jquery plugin for example) and use `mousewheel` there, it doesn't work on sites that used `wheel` event.

On the contrary if I use `wheel` event in script - it will broke sites that used `mousewheel`.

What to do in this situation? (and sorry for my english).

**Update**

Thanks to Tintu C Raju:

As per MDN "the wheel event is fired when a wheel button of a pointing device (usually a mouse) is rotated. This event replaces the non-standard deprecated mousewheel event."

Comment: the last time i had to use mousewheel events it was a huge pain to get it working the same in all browsers.. this plugins saved my life: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/

Comment: As per MDN "the wheel event is fired when a wheel button of a pointing device (usually a mouse) is rotated. This event replaces the non-standard deprecated mousewheel event."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MDN "the wheel event is fired when a wheel button of a pointing device (usually a mouse) is rotated. This event replaces the non-standard deprecated mousewheel event."